# Fatal error with Symfony 2.5.0

Tags: symfony

I have installed symfony2 through composer :

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition usr/share/nginx/www/symfony/
```

Everything ges smooth until I try to visit the main page I have this error :

```
Interface 'Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\ResourceInterface' not found
```

Also the doc don't talk about 2.5.0 , latest doc was about 2.3.0 and the Symfony 3 directory ? I just say no

Comment: Try running `composer install` and/or `composer update` within the project (where the `composer.json` file is located)

Comment: it says 
Nothing to install or update
and carries on

Comment: I don't see a version flag in your `create-project` command. Delete what you've done so far and try this instead: `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /usr/share/nginx/www/symfony/ "2.5.*"`

Comment: It's not mandatory, if you don't specify the flag version , it installs the last version. and it did because I have 2.5.0

Comment: Okay. Try deleting your `vendor` folder and run `composer install` again. Also post the contents of your `composer.json` file

Comment: I went to web/config , I fixed some problems like date.timezone and the problem vanished. 
But I'm still facing problems. So if I'm stuck again , I will delete all the vendors and do as you said